# Which one is correct, 'in' or 'at'?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

I fixed a computer in the Accounting Office. vs I fixed a computer at the Accounting Office.

Comment: Were you at the Accounting Office or did the Accounting Office receive the fax?

Comment: Either could be correct - _in_ if you think of the Office as a room or department in a large building, _at_ if it is an organisation with its own premises.